# What does the --deep flag do?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm using the `--deep` flag on a cocoa project that uses 3rd party frameworks. The aggregated content needs to be signed and this flag does the trick when added on "Other Code Signing Flags" in build settings.

I'm unable to find documentation on what the flag actually does. Can someone tell me or point me in the right direction ?

Comment: It's possible the framework writer used a DTS incident to learn to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Xcode 5 shipped, it installed a new version of `codesign(1)` in `/usr/bin`, one that includes `--deep` as a compiler option.  `--deep` allows all bundles that are compiled and linked after the flag is passed to recursively be code signed with the options sent to `codesign`.  It is important to note that `--deep`  must be placed strategically, as applying the same flags to every bundle won't work in some cases, and once `--deep` is passed, all subsequent options are used recursively.

As it is a code signing tool, move the `--deep` flag to `Other Code Signing Flags` in order for it to work properly (as a compilation flag, I assume it is ignored, as it is undocumented)

[image]

Comment: NDA. Good answer but still...